# Return a new promise and wait in Ember Data if response is 202

Tags: ajax, ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data, promise

We have an import process in our application that is handled by the server in the background, but is initiated by the user in our Ember app. If the import process hasn't completed after the transition, I'd like to send back a 202 response and have Ember re-try the request in 500ms.

I'd like to use Ember's internal features to handle this (loading route & regular model setter), so I tried over-riding the `RESTAdapter.ajax` method. I'm currently getting the generic error `Error while processing route: import` when trying to load the route. How can I achieve this behavior?

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend
  ajax: (url, type, options) ->
    adapter = this
    new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) ->
      hash = adapter.ajaxOptions(url, type, options)
      hash.success = (json, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        # begin modifications
        if jqXHR and jqXHR.status is 202
          return Ember.run.later adapter, (->
            this.ajax(url, type, options)
          ), 500
        else
          # end modifications
          return Ember.run null, resolve, json

      hash.error = (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        Ember.run null, reject, adapter.ajaxError(jqXHR)

      Ember.$.ajax hash
    , "DS: RESTAdapter#ajax " + type + " to " + url)
```

Comment: Assuming this is CS - please tag this as coffeescript.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the desired functionality by checking an endpoint on my server in the `beforeModel` method of my route. If the server is still processing the background job, the router aborts the transition and transitions to a secondary route that displays a nice message to the user and continually checks the endpoint on the server until the process is completed. Once completed, it then transitions back to the original route.

```
App.ImportRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  beforeModel: (transition) ->
    router = @
    $.get('/import/loading', "json").done (data)->
      if data
        transition.abort()
        router.transitionTo('importGateway')
  model: (params) ->
    @store.find('myModel')

App.ImportGatewayController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  init: ->
    @getStatus()
  getStatus: ->
    controller = @
    $.get('/import/loading', "json").done (data)->
      if data
        Ember.run.later controller, (-> @getStatus()), 500
      else
        controller.transitionToRoute('import')
```